# express.js express-resource POST (create) req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Windows.

Node 0.8 express.js/express-resource

```
// Configuration of Express Application for all environments
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    //app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // for static assets (css)
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/..')); // for static assets (css)

    app.use(app.router);
});
app.resource("data", require('.....js'));
```

---

> Send POST /data (in FireBug):  account[foo]   bar name    New

in created method (req, res)

**req.body is undefined.**

There are some talks in the internet about a like problem (with bodyParser or Router), but I could not fix it.

A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Just in case for someone: I called app.get(..) before bodyParser middleware.

Comment: Not clear if what you're describing is the bug or the fix. :/

Comment: My `request.body` didn't work because I didn't set the BodyParser using `app.use(express.bodyParser());`. After that, it was mandatory to put it above App.Get() or the like to have the `request.body` defined.
@FRD - Yes, it is the solution that indirectly describes the problem.